# Sprite not keeping track of count

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

The following code I'm using is to end the game when I my number of balls in the scene reaches zero. Now I'm not getting any error when I put the code in but it doesn't do any thing as of counting the balls and reacting to that count. I am fairly new to sprite kit so I understand that this is a problem that comes so easy to others but this is the first time of worked with reacting to the count of a certain sprite in a scene so please help.

```
SKSpriteNode *ball;
int numberOfBalls = 3;

@implementation EasyScene

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    if ([self isGameWon]) {
    EasyEndGameScene *end = [EasyEndGameScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:end transition:[SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:1]];
}
}

-(BOOL)isGameWon {
int numberOfBalls = 3;
for (SKNode* node in self.children) {
    if ([node.name isEqual: ball]) {
        numberOfBalls = 0;
    }
}
return numberOfBalls =0;
}

- (void) addBalls:(CGSize)size {
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //create brick sprite from image
    SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball-image"];
    ball.name = @"ball";
    //resize balls
    ball.size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width/5.5, self.size.width/5.5);
    //position and space out balls
    int xPos = size.width/3 * (i+.5);
    int yPos = self.size.height - (self.size.width/7);
    ball.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);
    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.width/2];
    ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
    ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bottomEdgeCategory;

    [self addChild:ball];

}
}
```

In the following code I got rid of the Global Variable and tested all nodes for the specified name of @"ball" and return YES if none were found:

```
   static const uint32_t ballCategory   = 1;       //00000000000000000000000000000001
   static const uint32_t edgeCategory  = 2;       //00000000000000000000000000000010
   static const uint32_t bottomEdgeCategory = 4;       //00000000000000000000000000000100

   SKSpriteNode *ball;

   @implementation EasyScene

  -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

   //create placeholder for the "non ball" object
   SKPhysicsBody *notTheBall;
   SKPhysicsBody *theBall;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
    notTheBall = contact.bodyB;
    theBall = contact.bodyA;
     } else {
    notTheBall = contact.bodyA;
    theBall = contact.bodyB;
     }

    if (notTheBall.categoryBitMask == bottomEdgeCategory) {
    NSLog(@"hit bottom edge");
    //        SKAction *playSFX = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"gameover.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
    //        [self runAction:playSFX];
     //        EasyEndGameScene *end = [EasyEndGameScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
     //        [self.view presentScene:end transition:[SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:1]];
    //        [GameState sharedInstance].score = 0;
    //        [gameMusic pause];
    [theBall.node removeFromParent];
    }

    if ([self isGameWon]) {
    EasyEndGameScene *end = [EasyEndGameScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:end transition:[SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:1]];
    }
    }

    -(BOOL)isGameWon {
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (SKNode* node in self.children)
    if ([node.name isEqual:ball])
        count++;
    return count == 0;
    }

    - (void) addBalls:(CGSize)size {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //create brick sprite from image
    SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball-image"];
    ball.name = @"ball";
    //resize balls
    ball.size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width/5.5, self.size.width/5.5);
    //position and space out balls
    int xPos = size.width/3 * (i+.5);
    int yPos = self.size.height - (self.size.width/7);
    ball.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);
    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.width/2];
    ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
    ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bottomEdgeCategory;

    [self addChild:ball];

    }
    }
```

Comment: set a breakpoint to verify the code is executing as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `ball` global variable, as it's not needed.
2. Test all nodes for the specified name of `@"ball"` and return `YES` if none were found:

   ```
   -(BOOL)isGameWon {
       for (SKNode* node in self.children)
          if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"ball"])
              return NO;
       return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok that worked to end the game when one ball goes away. That's some progress made though. But I do need it to only end when I have 0 balls left. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @NicholasWhitley OK, I've updated my answer and I believe it *should* work now...  let me know.

Comment: Ok I think I'm doing it right but it's still just ending the game when the first ball hits it. I added the code that I have so you can see if it has any errors. (sorry it's a lil' messy, the editing got messed up). Thanks @Droppy

Comment: You will need to update your question with the modified code (it can go at the end after the other code).

Comment: Just put it up in the question. @Droppy

Comment: @NicholasWhitley You aren't using my implementation of `isGameWon`.  Also that bitmask code looks broken (you need to use `&` to test for one or more bits in a bitmask, not `<` and `==`).

Comment: Ok for some reason your edit didn't pop up, it just showed the first answer the last few times. But it is working fine now. And as for the Bitmask code it's working for me for right now but I am still new to this so I have no clue how to use & for Bitmask. This is the first time I honestly think I would need to use it. But thanks @Droppy and if I wanted to end the game when I reach just one ball instead of 0, would that be easy to do from the code you gave me or is it something totally different?

Comment: @NicholasWhitley You would need to count the number of nodes with the name `@"ball"` and make it `return count == 1;` instead.  A bit like my first edit, except using the string `@"ball"` and not the global variable `ball` (which you should delete).

Comment: I deleted the global the second time around, ok hopefully I can figure this one out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
return numberOfBalls == 0
```

in your isgameWon method

you forget an extra =